# How do I make sure that multiple set states happen simultaneously, in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, setstate

I have a block of code that has multiple set states and two of these, mainfilters and currentPage are the dependency array to a useEffect that makes an API call. I need to make sure that the API call happens only once, when both mainfilters and currentPage have been set.

```
if (event.type === "set") {
      setShowCalendar(false);

      const dateFromCalendar = new Date(
        event.nativeEvent.timestamp
      ).toISOString();

      setOrders([]);

      setCurrentPage(1);
      setMainfilters((prevFilters: mainFilterInterface) => ({
        ...prevFilters,
        orderDate: dateFromCalendar,
      }));
    }
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetchAllOrders(true);
  }, [mainfilters, currentPage]);
```

I have done multiple set states just like this one in other places knowing that React batches them, and got my desired result (a single API call when both are set), but in this case, it isn't working as expected. Is it because the calculation of the dateFromCalendar is taking time? Is there any workaround to this to make sure both set states happen together?

Comment: You can add an `if` statement to the `useEffect` callback, something like `if (mainfilters && currentPage) { fetchAllOrders(true); }`

Comment: can you say more about "isn't working as expected"?  You may want to keep state (or a ref) that keeps track of whether the API call has been made for the combination of your page & filters.  You can also combine the two states into a single state object.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main approach to do so: either with a condition:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (mainfilters && currentPage)
       fetchAllOrders(true);
  }, [mainfilters, currentPage]);
```

Or you can group your states in a bigger object that contains all states, and update them at the same time:

```
const [state,setState] = useState({
   mainfilters:undefined,
   currentPage:undefined
})
```

And when you want to update those 2 states at the same time:

```
setState({
   mainfilters:{orderDate: dateFromCalendar},
   currentPage:1
   })
```